# SpotBugs Eclipse Plugin Logging

Tags: java, eclipse, spotbugs

I am trying to log details inside of a custom SpotBugs Plugin being executed inside of Eclipse.  However, I can't get anything to output to the console.   This is what I have:

```java
import edu.umd.cs.findbugs.log.ConsoleLogger;
import edu.umd.cs.findbugs.log.Logger;

public class BugDetector extends CFGDetector {
    private final BugReporter bugReporter;

    public BugDetector(BugReporter bugReporter) {
        this.bugReporter = bugReporter;
    }

    /**
     * Initializes and launches the analysis for a method, and checks the state
     * at the exit node for possible exit-while-locked errors.
     */
    @Override
    protected void visitMethodCFG(MethodDescriptor methodDescriptor, CFG cfg) throws CheckedAnalysisException {

     system.out.println("This should work!!");

    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you’re importing logging classes and not using them? Don’t you need to use them?

Comment: @nitind I have tried using them- but I don't get any output.